# Defining a custom `toString` in Flow 0.34

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have some function that I want to have a custom `toString` property, like this:

```
var Foo = function () {};
Foo.prototype.toString = function () { return 'hi'; };
```

[Here's a live example of the code.](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVA3AhgJzAMTjjAF4woBXAOwGMAXASzirAAoBKMAbwF8BuVITgA6AA444dSQE9RAU2FSAynRwMqAc1Llq9Jiw7cwOOXQo4WAcgAWDS3zD8gA)

In Flow 0.33 it works without an error, but in Flow 0.34 it produces an error:

```
4: Foo.prototype.toString = function () { return 'hi'; };
   ^ Object. Covariant property `toString` incompatible with contravariant use in
4: Foo.prototype.toString = function () { return 'hi'; };
   ^ assignment of property `toString`
```

Is this a bug in my code or in Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the covariance constraint with an `any` typecast:

```
(Foo.prototype : any).toString = function () { return 'hi'; };
```

Your code isn't wrong, flow is just enforcing a particular style.

Answer (score 0):

While Flow does have limited support for this style of class declarations, I highly recommend using the ES6 syntax. The one-shot declaration style helps Flow more easily understand the code.

```
class Foo {
  toString() {
    return 'hi';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A super silly way to do it (tricking the transpiler; avoid if possible):

```
Object.assign(Utils, { ['to'+'String']: (s/*:any*/)/*:string*/ => ''+ s });
```

I like the any casting example better in the top answer above.

```
(Utils/*:any*/).toString = (s/*:any*/)/*:string*/ => ''+ s;
```

However, I also needed this, (if you change the method signature, when you go to invoke it):

```
Utils.stringEquals = (a/*:any*/,b/*:any*/)/*:%checks*/ =>
    (Utils/*:any*/).toString(a) === (Utils/*:any*/).toString(b);
```